# Можно ли bxSlider-у как то задать параметры для для блока с текстом на слайде?

Tags: javascript, bxslider

Необходимо на нескольких слайдах разместить полупрозрачные блоки с текстом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно ли bxSlider-у как то задать параметры для для блока с текстом на слайде?

Да. Можно.

Это делается с помощью HTML и CSS.

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/hill_trees.jpg" />
     <div class="ПОЛУПРОЗРАЧНЫЙ">Текст на слайде</div>
 </li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/me_trees.jpg" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/houses.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s2L9P/

Либо использовать встроенные captions (менее гибкий вариант).

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  captions: true
});

<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/tree_root.jpg" title="Funky roots" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/hill_road.jpg" title="The long and winding road" /></li>
  <li><img src="/images/730_200/trees.jpg" title="Happy trees" /></li>
</ul>
```

http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

Comment: В таком случае не нужно  прописывать "captions true" и вообще не использовать атрибут _title_ ?

Comment: Или так, или как тут - http://bxslider.com/examples/image-slideshow-captions

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/s2L9P/